# CPQ Price Rule best practice on formula fields dependency calculations

Tags: cpq

Can you please provide the best practice to write price Rule if we are using the formula field for calculations on Quote line Editors?

The Problem I am facing:
Sometimes my calculation button is working sometimes not after adding a few product rules.

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, it's very important to order Price rules by events (On Initialization, Before Calculate, On Calculate, After Calculate). It means you, actually, controls what and when should be calculated.
Salesforce itself doesn't recommend to have more then 50 price rules - otherwise, it will  influence UI perfomance.

Other suggestions are applied to specific field calculations (dates, formula, currency etc). For example, for date fields you can only use data format as follows `YYYY-MM-DD`.

[This documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cpq_price_rule_considerations.htm&type=5) holds other suggestions that you may need consider.

Please take a look at [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269437/salesforce-cpq-is-it-possible-for-the-price-rules-to-send-mails/335173#335173) about Price Rules debugging.